# Conditionally add markup based on model value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I test the value of a Model.IsCopy and render the Part Num textbox if false?

I tried using @Model.IsCopy but it's value is different than the value in @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.IsCopy).  Seems @Model is the empty class while m is the value passed into the Partial View.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PartNum)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.IsCopy)
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><h4 class="text-info"> Details</h4></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"> <hr /></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="30%">Part Num</td>
        <td>
             @{ if (@Model.IsCopy == false)
                {
                   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PartNum,  new { ReadOnly = "true", Visibility = "true" })
              }
                }
        </td>                       
    </tr>
```

Inspecting in the browser shows the hidden field to be true but the Html.TextboxFor still renders.

```
<input name="IsCopy" id="IsCopy" type="hidden" value="true" data-val-required="The IsCopy field is required." data-val="true" data-bind="value:IsCopy">
```

Comment: I know this will sound a little condescending but; are you sure? I've tsted your code and the textbox only appears when IsCopy is set to false. There should be no discrepancy between your hidden input value and Model.IsCopy

Comment: Interesting...there is another caveat...The view is a cshtml file but it is being opened via the Telerik popup editor in a Grid.  I wonder if that element is causing the issue...  I have asked the question in a Telerik forum.  Awaiting their answer.